# adding the values of two lables

Tags: c#

I am trying to get this piece of code to work. I Cannot understand why it’s not working. Can somebody please have look and see if l'am doing something wrong here?

The error message is

> "Input string was not in correct format"

```
sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT salesT, SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[salesA])) AS [A],
                           SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[salesB])) AS [B], 
                           FROM details WHERE method= 'cont'  GROUP BY salesT", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Select("salesT= '01062015'").FirstOrDefault();

if (dr != null)
{
    label31.Text = dr["A"].ToString();
    label30.Text = dr["B"].ToString();
}

sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT salesT, SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[salesA])) AS [A], 
                            SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[salesB])) AS [B], 
                            FROM details WHERE method= 'cred'  GROUP BY salesT", con);
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
sda1.Fill(ds1);
DataRow dr1 = ds1.Tables[0].Select("salesT= '01062015'").FirstOrDefault();

if (dr1 != null)
{
    label22.Text = dr1["A"].ToString();
    label21.Text = dr1["B"].ToString();                            
}

int iV1 = Convert.ToInt32(label31.Text); 
int iV2 = Convert.ToInt32(label22.Text);
int iV3 = iV1 + iV2;
label40.Text = iV3.ToString();
```

Comment: On which line exactly? Can you please debug your code and check your `label31.Text` and `label22.Text` values and your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Either `label31.Text` or `label22.Text` is not anything that can be converted to an `int`. Look at it's values, best by using the debugger.

Comment: It breaks at this point  int iV1 = Convert.ToInt32(label31.Text); The value is 408.34

Comment: If `dr == null` or `dr1 == null`, then you have unitialized labels -> exception.

Comment: @callasda Clearly, `408.34` is not a valid `int`. Have you ever try to parse it to double instead?

Comment: if i remove the the last 4 lines, it all works, but of course there are no totals inside labels 31 and 22

Comment: Soner. Should I do this. Convert.ToDouble(label31.Text);   ?

Comment: @callasda Added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your labels aren't null or empty:

```
sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT salesT, SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[salesA])) AS [A],SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[salesB])) AS [B], 
                                   FROM details WHERE method= 'cont'  GROUP BY salesT", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Select("salesT= '01062015'").FirstOrDefault();
    if (dr != null)
    {
        label31.Text = dr["A"].ToString();
        label30.Text = dr["B"].ToString();
    }
    sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT salesT, SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[salesA])) AS [A], SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[salesB])) AS [B], 
                                   FROM details WHERE method= 'cred'  GROUP BY salesT", con);
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    sda1.Fill(ds1);
    DataRow dr1 = ds1.Tables[0].Select("salesT= '01062015'").FirstOrDefault();
    if (dr1 != null)
    {
        label22.Text = dr1["A"].ToString();
        label21.Text = dr1["B"].ToString();                            
    }
    //You declare A as Decimal, so Integer doesn't work for you
    double iV1 = 0, iV2 = 0;        
    double.TryParse(label31.Text, out iV1); 
    double.TryParse(label22.Text, out iV2);
    double iV3 = iV1 + iV2;

    //Or decimal value type
    //decimal iV1, iV2;        
    //decimal.TryParse(label31.Text, out iV1); 
    //decimal.TryParse(label22.Text, out iV2);
    //decimal iV3 = iV1 + iV2;
    label40.Text = iV3.ToString();
```

Comment: Yes, [A] a [B] returns decimal. So, you must convert to double or decimal.

Comment: Christian Amado solution has worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

> [It breaks at this point int iV1 = Convert.ToInt32(label31.Text); The
>   value is 408.34](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917405/adding-the-values-of-two-lables#comment49872479_30917405)

Clearly, `408.34` is not a valid integer. That's why you get `FormatException`.

Closest thing you get is as a `double`. Parse it to double with an `IFormatProvider` that has `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
double iV1 = double.Parse(label31.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will make your `iV1` as a `408.34`. You can use this value with `iV2` for assigning to your label text.

If you wanna truncate the fractional part of if, just do it like;

```
int i = (int)iV1; // i will be 408
```